# How to change opacity of child-element when hovering his parent

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

```
<section class="album" role="listitem" onmouseover="this.albumHeader.style.opacity = 0.6">
    <a href="@HrefHelper.ToAlbum(album.Title, 0)">
        <img src="@albumPreview.GenerateSrcHTML()" height="@albumPreview.PreviewHeight" width="@albumPreview.PreviewWidth" />
    </a>
    <header id="albumHeader">
        <p>@album.Title</p>
    </header>
</section>
```

This JS-code:
    `this.albumHeader.style.opacity = 0.6`
somewhy is erroneous: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". The idea is when user hovers `<section class="album"...` the `<header>` inside (which is by default opacity:0.0) becomes visible. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question in the comment of @GMchris answer, here's an example with animation:

```
section.album header {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

section.album:hover > header {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Plunker example: [click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pG1q9gCVkMUN2H2blpNF?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following styles:

```
.parent:hover .child {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Of course, replace the selectors with you own.

Comment: Or you can do it with direct descendant tag selector: `.album:hover > header { opacity: 0.6; }`

Comment: In this particular case, the query selector would be: `.album:hover #albumHeader`

Comment: guys, is there a simple way to make it animated? fade? using CSS only? I came from WPF, and I am very new to this kind of things..

Comment: @52hertz you'll need to look up CSS animations for that

Comment: @jdforsythe I expected to fing something like animation:fade, duration:0.5.

Comment: @52hertz see my answer for example with simple animation. This is a very simple animation. They can get pretty complex.

Comment: @52hertz It's easier than a CSS animation. Do this:

.album #albumHeader {
transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.album:hover #albumHeader {
opacity: .5;
}

That'll cause a transition for the opacity of that element.

Answer (score -1):

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('albumHeader').style.opacity = 0.6"
```

note that the opacity will stay .6 unless you change it on mouse out as well.
A css solution would probably be easier to maintain.

Comment: the problem is that I got list of automatically generated "albumHeaders". as I understand, .getElementById return the first one...

Comment: In the case that you are going to potentially have more than one header, don't use an ID, but use a Class. That way you can do `document.getElementsByClassName('albumHeader')`. This will return an array containing all elements with that class.

Comment: going on what Tomasito665 said, you can use this.getElementsByClassName('albumHeader')[0].style.opacity = 0.6.  You have to change id='albumHeader' to class='albumHeader'